# One-liner to print first feature from GeoJSON

Tags: geojson, filter, ogrinfo, feature-filter

To make the findings from this [GDAL issue](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/3413) more discoverable, I'm posting here as well.

---

`ogr2ogr` has a `-limit` option. I couldn't find this option for `ogrinfo`, while `ogrinfo` has e.g. `-where`. I would like to use the same simplicity like with the `-where` flag, e.g. neither specify `select *` nor `from layer`.

I use it to look at actual values of a layer. `-so` only gives the column names and column types, and simply `ogrinfo` spams the terminal if you are doing it on a file with 2.5 mio features.

I'm working inside a JupyterLab and there is no way to start any GUI applications. There are only a Terminal, iPython console and Jupyter notebooks. Besides, Ctrl+C to stop the spamming might not be carried out for quite some time.

Simply doing `head file.geojson` does not work if the file has all its contents on one line.

How can I do something like `ogrinfo -limit 1` (`ogrinfo` has no `-limit` option) for a GeoJSON file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For GeoJSON this sort of works (adjust `-c` to your needs):

```
head -c 1000 HPG_2019_simplified.geojson
```

prints:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "HPG_2019_simplified",
"crs": {
"properties": {"name": "EPSG:31287"}, "type": "name"
},
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": "1", "NAME": "Hochalpen" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 183502.200000002980232, 410278.980000000447035 ], [ 183184.21000000089407, 410241.309999998658895 ], [ 182856.229999996721745, 411575.989999998360872 ], [ 182187.340000003576279, 411651.309999998658895 ], [ 181957.79, 411868.420000001788139 ], [ 181877.96000000089407, 412190.29 ], [ 182004.369999997317791, 412222.199999999254942 ], [ 181681.71000000089407, 412771.949999999254942 ], [ 182168.920000001788139, 412954.219999998807907 ], [ 181993.840000003576279, 413202.21000000089407 ], [ 182310.929999999701977, 413482.019999999552965 ], [ 183716.969999998807907, 413258.309999998658895 ], [ 184776.369999997317791, 413716.649999998509884 ], [ 184979.799999997019768, 413687.149999998509884 ], [ 184990.759999997913837, 41343
```