# One-liner to print first feature from GPKG

Tags: filter, ogrinfo, feature-filter, geopackage

To make the findings from this [GDAL issue](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/3413) more discoverable, I'm posting here as well.

---

`ogr2ogr` has a `-limit` option. I couldn't find this option for `ogrinfo`, while `ogrinfo` has e.g. `-where`. I would like to use the same simplicity like with the `-where` flag, e.g. neither specify `select *` nor `from layer`.

I use it to look at actual values of a layer. `-so` only gives the column names and column types, and simply `ogrinfo` spams the terminal if you are doing it on a file with 2.5 mio features.

I'm working inside a JupyterLab and there is no way to start any GUI applications. There are only a Terminal, iPython console and Jupyter notebooks. Besides, Ctrl+C to stop the spamming might not be carried out for quite some time.

How can I do something like `ogrinfo -limit 1` (`ogrinfo` has no `-limit` option) for a GPKG file?

---

This is not a duplicate of [One-liner to print first feature from GeoJSON](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/386331/one-liner-to-print-first-feature-from-geojson)

Comment: Can you expand this (and the other) question to describe the issue without us needing to go to git hub, otherwise there this question is likely to be closed as better discussed on the mailing list

Answer (score 0):

Proposed solutions by Jukka Rahkonen [jratike80](https://github.com/jratike80):

### Need to input layer name

`ogrinfo -sql "select * from layer limit 1" file.gpkg`

### Multiple lines, but can be put into script

```
ogr2ogr -f gpkg temp.gpkp %input_here% -limit 1
ogrinfo temp.gpkg -al
del temp.gpkg
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the data source has an entry with a `fid` of `1` you can do this:

`ogrinfo -al -fid 1 file.gpkg`